# Ligação módulos e pacotes

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Estou tentando implementar uma GUI com python3x e tkinter em scripts separados.

Tenho uma pasta 'gui_teste' organizado da seguinte forma:

- gui (subpasta): **unit**.py e app.py (tkinter)
- utils (subpasta): **unit**.py e functions.py
- **unit**.py (arquivo)
- principal.py (arquivo)

Quero fazer o seguinte:

1) o principal.py chama o app.py

2) no app.py tem botões e chamam funções no functions.py

3) quero que o functions.py imprima o resultado da função no GUI app.py, porém não estou conseguindo fazer essa ligação.

Os script estão assim:

principal.py:

```
from gui import app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.main()
```

app.py:

```
from tkinter import *
from utils import functions

class Application():
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        self.msg = Label(master, text= 'Primeira Mensagem')
        self.msg.pack()

        self.btnTrocaMsg = Button(master, text= 'Trocar', command= functions.trocaMsg)
        self.btnTrocaMsg.pack()

def main():
    root = Tk()
    Application(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

functions:

```
from gui import app

def trocaMsg():
    <caminho?>.msg['text'] = 'Mensagem trocada.'
```

Qual o caminho?

Os arquivos estão adequadamente agrupados nas pastas?

Alterei o app.py e functions.py:

app.py:

```
(...)
    self.btnTrocaMsg = Button(master, text= 'Trocar', command= ***self.troca***)
    self.btnTrocaMsg.pack()


***def troca(self):
    a = functions.trocaMsg(self)
    self.msg['text'] = a***
(...)
```

No functions.py:

```
from gui import app


    ***def trocaMsg(msg):
        return 'Mensagem trocada.'***
```

A aplicação deu certo. Porém, pergunto: o código está da forma correta?

Comment: eu faço isso com frequencia, eu costumo usar herança de classe e funciona que é uma beleza

Comment: Pelo o que eu vi está tudo certinho.

Comment: Pois é, mas não estou conseguindo retornar a 'Mensagem trocada' para a GUI, tentei colocar o root, etc, mas não consegui. Só está faltando esse detalhe do <caminho?>. Acontece que ainda não entendi muito bem a questão das classes, instanciar, passar, self, etc.

Comment: Elton Nunes e JeanExtreme002, fiz alterações no código, podem dar as suas opiniões, por gentileza.